# How to use CURDATE() in PDO function for multiple insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've a function like this :

```
  function insert2(){
      $i=0;

      $query = "insert into ".$this->table_name." values(?,?,?,'','',?)";
      # i've try below code, but just insert 1 row to mysql
      # $query = "insert into ".$this->table_name." values(?,?,?,'','',CURDATE())";
      foreach ($this->ik as $key => $value){
          $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
          $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->ia);
          $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);
          $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->nn[$key]);
          # $stmt->bindParam(6, CURDATE());
          $stmt->execute();
          $i++;
      }
      return $i;
    }
```

how to fix multiple insert just insert 1 row?

any idea please?

**EDIT**

my column look's like

```
|------|------|------|--?--|--?--|------|
|  ia  |  ik  |  nn  |  ?  |  ?  | date |
|------|------|------|-----|-----|------|
```

each form of input should insert 1 row to mysql like you see below:

[Form interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UEQn.png)

example output of input form is

`Array ( [ia] => 6 [ik] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) [nn] => Array ( [0] => 80 [1] => 79 [2] => 79 [3] => 80 ) )`

> ***If you want to downvote my question, also please comment why***

Comment: $dateTime = date_create('now')->format('Y-m-d);        $query = "insert into ".$this->table_name." values(?,?,?,'','',$date_Time)";

Comment: If it just inserts one row, you need to check the value of `$this->ik`, and check for mysql errors that it throws back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the value in the SQL...

```
$query = "insert into ".$this->table_name." values(?,?,?,'','',curdate())";
```

Comment: i've try that syntax in my comment code but it just insert 1 row

Comment: How many rows should it insert?  If possible - put `null` in the date to try it.

Comment: i've try inserting 4 row to mysql, but it just insert 1 row and the other's is not inserted

Comment: Do you have an error?  It could be duplicate records, depending on what your primary key is defined as.  BTW it's usually better if you list the column names your inserting into - it saves problems if the table is re-created which can sometimes mean the fields are in a different order.

Comment: If your getting one row with the correct date (curdate) then it shows that this is not the problem, so it's just a case of finding out what is.